# Flash socket security policy (local+remote socket access)

Tags: flash, sockets, flashdevelop, haxe, neko

I want to setup a Client(flash)-Server(neko) socket connection to be possible:

1. On localhost - for local testing
2. Internet swf(kongregate) to my server - for production/beta testing

I read a lot about policy here and on google and become confused a bit.

Questions are:

1. Is it possible, considering I cannot change everything on kongregate(but I can change everything on my site)
2. If it is - what modifiers should I apply to my Client(swf) and Server 
   for socket connections to become possible?
3. Is there some difference for local(file://) and remote(http://) swf locations and
   how to bypass that?

I use FlashDevelop/haxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. See "[Setting up a socket policy file server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html)" document for example. In short your server should listen for client request **<policy-file-request/>** and reply with  socket policy string;
2. Compile your client for "network access". In FlashDevelop window Project/Properties/Compiler Options set **Use network services** to **True** (set by default);
3. To test client locally you should add project directories where SWF file placed to trusted directories for example via Windows Control panel/Flash/Developer tools...Trusted directories (sorry I don't know exact english title of this tab). But FlashDevelop makes it automatically.